# How to create a upload script with multiple file select like Facebook with a progress bar?

Tags: php, html, ajax, flash

I was just wondering that is there a way to create a multiple file select like Facebook (using flash, I think.) and with a progress bar that show every photos progress in one progress bar.
Have a clue or a script which can be customized and can be used easily? Well, I'm too new to PHP that's why I have been asking for your help. If you have a script like this please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/).
Requires the MooTools JavaScript framework and is Flash-based.

Comment: One question, from where I would download it??

Comment: The download link is about half the page down. It is hosted on github, you can use git to download the newest version or choose from a download found here: https://github.com/digitarald/digitarald-fancyupload.

Comment: @Jack: Where it says "download" on the page you were linked to.

Answer (score 1):

This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error  found)
and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures.
If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.